# Unable to get protperty "add" of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo un Datatable de jquery y necesito agregar una nueva fila:
uso lo siguente:

```
var tabla = $('#tabla').Datatable();

tabla.row.add({
 "name": "Nombre1",
 "postion": "Postion1"
});
```

Este código vale en todos los exploradores, pero en internet explorer me da ese error.

Comment: Internet explorer no sigue las normas de ECMAScript, en vez usa su propio dialecto de Javascript desarrollado por Microsoft. No te preocupes por eso, nadie usa Internet Explorer. Saludos

Comment: Te dejo un [enlace](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#:~:text=JScript%20es%20la%20implementaci%C3%B3n%20de,y%20el%20Windows%20Scripting%20Host.), por si quieres leer al respecto.